# How to globally change colour of all TikZ diagrams in a document?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am writing a book with a large number of diagrams drawn in TikZ. I want to change the colour of all diagrams (lines and text) uniformly from black to another colour (say red). Can I achieve this with a global command without having to manually specify the colour for each diagram?

Comment: try `\tikzset{draw=red,text=blue,fill=pink}`

Comment: @AndréC with the above command only text is working, draw and fill are not working.

Comment: try `\tikzset{every picture/.style={draw=red,text=blue,fill=pink}}`

Comment: Thanks! This works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.